# Play and Scala, type match and succesful compile, but I think it's a mismatch

Tags: scala, types, playframework

I was implementing some PlayFramework custom `Actions` when I came up with a question, let me explain it a little bit:

This is the code for my custom action:

```
object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] with Controller {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    request.session.get("username").fold 
    {
      Future.successful(Forbidden(views.html.forbidden()(request)))
    } {
      username => block(new AuthenticatedRequest(username, request))
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code for my controller action:

```
def index = AuthenticatedAction { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}
```

The thing is that `AuthenticatedAction` needs a function that returns a `Future[Result]`.

- In the "forbidden" part of the `invokeBlock[A]...` I wrap the result in a `Future`
- But in the "authenticated" part, the `block` function does not return a `Future[Result]` and instead returns a `Result` (see `def index`).

The code above compiles and I see the desired page, but I don't understand why it works. Also, if I wrap the result of the `block` function in a `Future`, the Intelli IDEA inspector tells me "type mismatch" specifying that wants a `Result` instead of a `Future[Result]`.

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is. Can anyone give some light to my mind?

Comment: The `block` *does* return a `Future[Result]` - it says so right in the signature of `invokeBlock`. Does calling `invokeBlock` with your `index` work? And what is the type of `index` (try mousing over it in your IDE)? - I don't know Play well enough to be sure, but that `AuthenticatedAction` could be doing one of several things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a future you must do this:

```
def index = AuthenticatedAction.async { implicit request =>
  Future.successful(Ok)
}
```

If you look in the API (link below), there is the apply method which takes in a "=> Result" where as .async method takes in a "=> Future[Result]".

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder

Comment: I was trying to understand the source code, I think I've had enough understanding by looking at the code, even some concepts (type programming basically) still are out of reach. I'll take a look again in a few months. Thanks :)

Comment: You're not alone. I've been working with scala for almost two years now, and looking at play's source code is still very intimidating to me. But that's why they have API's right =)

Answer (score 0):

```
block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[Result]
```

block is function that takes (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) and returns Future[Result].

If you wrap block then result type is Future[Future[]]

Comment: Yep, but the implementation of my block in def index ... returns a Result not a Future[Result] that's my question